# Compiling GCC compiler....shows error

Tags: compiling, gcc

So I started to setup for AVR programing and I found [this nice tutorial](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/setup-unix.html) to guide me.

I am on step 3 of the tutorial.
When I type the command:
 `make CC="cc --no-cpp-precomp"`

I get this error:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If there's no `Makefile`, then that suggests the preceding `./configure` step did not complete successfully

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've searched around a bit more and found that the "make" command doesn't work because the previous ./configure command doesn't work. I read the full error in the terminal and it said to install gmp, mpc and mpfr (Newest versions). In the gcc directory there is a file that downloads them for you and installs them nicely. Here's the link, It'll guide you on how to install these packages

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC

Good luck.